# How to cancel previous onRegionChangeComplete handler in react-native-maps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

The problem occurs when making two fast map movements, the `onRegionChangeComplete` is called twice consecutively but as `setState` is an async operation when the first call sets the state it roll back the map to the previous position, then the second movement set state to the latest position and that triggers a new `onRegionChangeComplete`, and so.

Please help to avoid this kind of issue.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the time needed to resolve setState is not that much, i put a 200ms(which is a big value for here) timeout and saw your issue. if your app is suffering from jumps of set states, you have serious performance issue.

Comment: To be honest, I have to call Google Place API to get the address.